# Непонятки jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Вот есть страница А, с нее посылается аякс на страницу Б, оттуда возвращается на страницу А через `.html(data)`. На странице Б формируется скрипт, который имеет такой вид `$('.class').click(так далее)`.

Проблема такая: при отправке 2 раза аякса возвращается 2 скрипта и получается что при нажатие на кнопку скрипт обрабатывается 2 раза, если 3 раза отправить аякс то 3 раза будет, как сделать так, что предыдущий скрипт стирался и оставался только один всегда, хоть сколько отправляй аякс

Comment: ну так удаляйте перед добавлением.

Comment: зачем вы вообще пересылаете скрипт?

Answer (score 1):

Очищайте событие.

```
$(".class").unbind( "click" );
```

или не добавляйте, если такое событие уже есть

Comment: добавлять событие тоже через bind $(".class").bind( "click", function(){код -запрос аякс});

Answer (score 1):

На странице А написать один раз скрипт вида:

```
$(document).on('click','.class', function() {
    // some code    
});
```

На странице Б формировать и передавать лишь html, без скриптов.
Описанный выше обработчик будет обслуживать клики по всем элементам с классом class. И не нужно ничего стирать и переназначать.